# How to make a service for a Signup form in Angular js

Tags: angularjs, forms

I am trying to understand how angular work in the client side when submitting forms. I halfway there but I get an error, and I can't move forward.

In my controller I have the following code:

```
 $scope.SaveData = function (data) {
        if ($scope.submitText == 'Save') {
            $scope.submitted = true;
            $scope.message = '';

            if ($scope.isFormValid) {
                $scope.submitText = 'Please Wait...';
                $scope.User = data;
                RegistrationService.SaveFormData(data).then(function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                    if (response == 'Success') {
                        //have to clear form here
                        ClearForm();
                    }
                    $scope.submitText = "Save";
                });
            }
            else {
                $scope.message = 'Please fill required fields value';
            }
        }
    }
```

And then in my registration service I have the following :

```
.factory('RegistrationService', function ($http, $q, $location) { 
    //here $q is a angularjs service with help us to run asynchronous function and return result when processing done
    var fac = {};
    fac.SaveFormData = function (data) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http({
            url: '/api/Users',
            method: 'POST',
            data: d,
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
        }).success(function (d) {
            // Success callback
            defer.resolve(d);
            $locationu.url('/');
        }).error(function (e) {
            //Failed Callback
            alert('Error!');
            defer.reject(e);
        });
        return defer.promise;
    }
    return fac;
});
```

What does `data:d` represent ? How should I defined so I can process the form?
I have the data in the scope but when I call SaveFormData I encounter problem with `data:d` it says undefined and I can't understand why is that so? And what does that part of the code do? 
Any reference tutorial and explanation is welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because d is not defined, "data: d" is where you set the JSON object Being passed to the server in the request, bind you fields with ng-model="formDara.fieldname" then pass formData to your saveFormData(formData) and change "data: d" to "data: data".